# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25

Tags: sockets, web-applications

I get this error while running web services using a web application.

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8083 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8083

Source Error: 


Line 108:        [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/VerifyFingerPrint", RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
Line 109:        public string VerifyFingerPrint([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="base64Binary")] byte[] VeriBmp, string empcode) {
Line 110:            object[] results = this.Invoke("VerifyFingerPrint", new object[] {
Line 111:                        VeriBmp,
Line 112:                        empcode});


Source File: D:\Mayuri1working\BOBFingerPrint\BOBFingerPrint\Web References\localhost\Reference.cs    Line: 110
```

Please help !

Comment: This means there's no service running on port 8083 on localhost.

Comment: Why do you say `:25` in the title, but `:8083` in the question? Which port are you using? Port 25 is normally used by SMTP, not a web service.

Comment: That code isn't PHP.

Comment: I'd say that no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. If you don't know what that means you could try googling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First update your web service references used in your application.
If web service references are not get updated, then check all files and folder containing source code files in your web service project solution and rebuild it and then update web references used in your project.
Else if its working fine then you need to check your network services used by your development server and windows firewall settings as suggested in above solutions.

I also encountered same problem and I came to know that I was referencing wrong folder having same name but used in another solution.

Enjoy codding.